# NLTK Python TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, nltk

Trying to run the code below:

```
import os
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
from collections import Counter

nltk.data.path.append(os.path('/usr/local/share/nltk_data'))

with open('output.txt', 'r') as input:
    text = input.read()
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    unigrams = ngrams(token, 1)
    bigrams = ngrams(token, 2)
    trigrams = ngrams(token, 3)
    fourgrams = ngrams(token, 4)
    fivegrams = ngrams(token, 5)

    print(Counter(bigrams))
```

However, I am getting the following error when running from terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NGram.py", line 7, in <module>
    nltk.data.path.append(os.path('/usr/local/share/nltk_data'))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have downloaded all NLTK packages and I'm pointing to the correct location in the `data.path.append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `'/usr/local/share/nltk_data'` is the path where your data exists, just do:

```
nltk.data.path = '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
```

When you use `append()`, you are trying to use `os.path.append()` which is part of the `os` library.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call the module `os.path` when you write `os.path('/usr/local/share/nltk_data')`. `path` is a module *within* the `os` module, and you cannot call a module like you can a function. You might have meant to call a method within `os` or `os.path`.